# How to display numbers that are skipped within a certain range mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

> I have query in mysql as follows

```
SELECT ont as next_ont_id FROM ont_activation WHERE olt_id =
'OLT-601167-1' AND lt = '1'  AND pon = '2' AND activation_status =
'Activated';
```

> Output: next_ont_id  65 67 68 69 70

> how to get a value of 66 in that output??

Comment: You can't select data that isn't there. There are a couple of workarounds (aka ugly hacks) however its best to handle these gaps in your application language rather than a database query.

Comment: If your goal is to remove gaps in your auto increment IDs, there's loads of reasons to not remove those gaps. That said, to answer the question,  why not select all IDs where `id-1` doesn't exist, and all IDs where `id+1` doesn't exist, and you have a list of exclusive ranges you can build from there where gaps are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with  PHP -

```
$val = explode(" ", "65 67 68 69 70");

$all = range($val[0], end($val)); // get all values between lowest & largest

print_r(array_diff($all, $val)); // check difference
```

Output -

```
Array
(
    [1] => 66
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that this is not a sampling error.
Perhaps you should index the data again.
in MySQL it is done like this

```
set @ROW = 0;
UPDATE `ont` SET `olt_id` = @ROW := @ROW+1 ORDER BY `olt_id` ASC;
```